# Ubuntu: apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have been trying to update apt-get on Ubuntu, but am failing in spite of having viewed a variety of different solutions to similar problems.

I am running the following command...

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I have received the following output...

```
Get:9 http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease [7,185 B]                                     
Err:9 http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: D2E3915347209000FA1C06D47CF8D72BE29DF322

...

W: GPG error: http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: D2E3915347209000FA1C06D47CF8D72BE29DF322
E: The repository 'http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried re-downloading the key, but still nothing will work.

EDIT: Following installation of the package, I received the same error...

```
smrk007@Atticus:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i repo-deb-build-0002.deb 
(Reading database ... 201875 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack repo-deb-build-0002.deb ...
Unpacking typesafe-repo (2.0-build-0003) over (2.0-build-0003) ...
Setting up typesafe-repo (2.0-build-0003) ...
Warning: The postinst maintainerscript of the package typesafe-repo
Warning: seems to use apt-key (provided by apt) without depending on gnupg or gnupg2.
Warning: This will BREAK in the future and should be fixed by the package maintainer(s).
Note: Check first if apt-key functionality is needed at all - it probably isn't!
Warning: apt-key should not be used in scripts (called from postinst maintainerscript of the package typesafe-repo)
OK
smrk007@Atticus:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                           
Get:3 https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian  Release [815 B]                                                                                             
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                                   
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]                                                    
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                                                             
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                              
Get:9 http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease [7,185 B]                                                                                            
Err:9 http://apt.typesafe.com unicorn InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: D2E3915347209000FA1C06D47CF8D72BE29DF322
```

To give some more context, I was trying to install the sbt command line tool for using scala right before this error occurred.

Comment: You need to both download the key signature and add it ot the apt keyring.  They provide a deb package that does it all for you - http://apt.typesafe.com/repo-deb-build-0002.deb

Comment: @ivanivan I followed your advice, and am still receiving the same error... Could the key be corrupted?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
```

Basically remove all the lists folders from the apt directory.
Add list directory with below command:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
```

Then try the below command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This also deletes the gpg certificates. You do not want to do that.  This will not improve the OP situation, quite by the contrary.